# Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, serialization, jackson

I have a simple controller that return a User object, this user have a attribute coordinates that have the hibernate property FetchType.LAZY.

When I try to get this user, I always have to load all the coordinates to get the user object, otherwise when Jackson try to serialize the User throws the exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

This is due to Jackson is trying to fetch this unfetched object. Here are the objects:

```
public class User{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonManagedReference("user-coordinate")
    private List<Coordinate> coordinates;
}

public class Coordinate {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference("user-coordinate")
    private User user;
}
```

And the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{username}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
        
    User user = userService.getUser(username);
        
    return user;
        
}
```

There is a way to tell Jackson to not serialize the unfetched objects? I've been looking other answers posted 3 years ago implementing jackson-hibernate-module. But probably it could be achieved with a new jackson feature.

My versions are:

- Spring 3.2.5
- Hibernate 4.1.7
- Jackson 2.2

Comment: approach described in these 2 links worked for me, [Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4 and Jackson-Module-Hibernate](http://blog.pastelstudios.com/2012/03/12/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-jackson-module-hibernate/)  and [FasterXML / jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate)

Comment: Thank you indybee, I've been watching the tutorial, spring 3.2.5 already have a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, but I cannot use it to avoid the non fetched lazy object, also I've tried to implementing the one in the tutorial, but nothing...

Comment: are you getting the same error "could not initialize proxy" or something different? (i used the additional HibernateAwareObjectMapper described in the articles with Spring 3.2.6 and Hibernate 4.1.7 and jackson 2.3)

Comment: Got it!! Since version 3.1.2 Spring have his own **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** and have almost the same behavior of the one in the tutorial, but the problem was that I am using Spring java config and I'm starting with javaconfigs. I was trying to make a *@Bean MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter*, instead of adding it to the HttpMessageConverters of Spring, maybe it's clearer in the answer :)

Comment: Is it broken in Spring Boot 2?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I finally found the solution! thanks to indybee for giving me a clue.

The tutorial [Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4 and Jackson-Module-Hibernate](http://blog.pastelstudios.com/2012/03/12/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-jackson-module-hibernate/) have a good solution for Spring 3.1 and earlier versions. But since version 3.1.2 Spring have his own **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** with almost the same functionality as the one in the tutorial, so we don't need to create this custom HTTPMessageConverter.

With javaconfig we don't need to create a **HibernateAwareObjectMapper** too, we just need to add the **Hibernate4Module** to the default **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** that Spring already have and add it to the HttpMessageConverters of the application, so we need to:

1. Extend our spring config class from **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter** and override the method **configureMessageConverters**.
2. On that method add the **MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter** with the **Hibernate4Module** registered in a previus method.

Our config class should look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyConfigClass extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    //More configuration....

    /* Here we register the Hibernate4Module into an ObjectMapper, then set this custom-configured ObjectMapper
     * to the MessageConverter and return it to be added to the HttpMessageConverters of our application*/
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Registering Hibernate4Module to support lazy objects
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        return messageConverter;

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //Here we add our custom-configured HttpMessageConverter
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    //More configuration....
}
```

If you have an xml configuration, you don't need to create your own MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter either, but you do need to create the personalized mapper that appears in the tutorial (HibernateAwareObjectMapper), so your xml config should look like this:

```
<mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper">
            <bean class="com.pastelstudios.json.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</mvc:message-converters>
```

Hope this answer be understandable and helps someone find the solution for this problem, any questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. However after a few tries, I found that the latest jackson at the moment (_2.4.2_) does _NOT_ work with spring 4.0.6. I still have the "no session" error. Only when I down graded jackson version back to 2.3.4 (or 2.4.2), did it start working.

Comment: Thanks for pointing MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter out! I was looking for a class like this for a while.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have just tested it and its working with Spring 4.2.4, Jackson 2.7.1-1 and JacksonDatatype 2.7.1 :)

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem in Spring Data REST.

Comment: This works perfectly for me except that I call

    hibernate5Module.enable(Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);

That was required to not return "null"

Comment: @rgdayo
It is working for json. then what about xml ?

Comment: don't forget to add Maven dependency.  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-hibernate5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.9</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: How to solve the same issue, if Springboot is used in place of Spring?. I have tried registering the Hibernate4 module(which is the version I have currently), but that did not solve my issue.

Comment: Been trying to fix this for two days and this answer finally fixed it! For those stuck, at the time of writing this, the only other thing I did was ensure I was using the latest spring / hibernate etc

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. FYI, your XML configuration need to be put inside <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven> in order to work. This also assume you have properly declared the schema location.

Comment: Not good solution, because: 1. Hibernate4Module is legacy. 2 Too much lines of code. 3. You are changing existing preconfigured Message Converter

Answer (score 50):

As of Spring 4.2 and using Spring Boot and javaconfig, registering the Hibernate4Module is now as simple as adding this to your configuration:

```
@Bean
public Module datatypeHibernateModule() {
  return new Hibernate4Module();
}
```

ref: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Comment: For Hibernate 5 (as in the current version of Spring Boot), it is `Hibernate5Module`. It additionally needs a dependency to `<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId><artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>`

Comment: Worked for me as well on Spring Boot 2.1. Was beginning to drive me crazy.

Comment: It's not clear how to implement this. I get an incompatible types error.

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me with Spring Boot 2.0.6 and Hibernate 5.

Comment: This was very helpful.  It should be pointed out that registering the Hibernate5Module class instance as a bean isn't enough.  If you wish to apply it to a single ObjectMapper instance,  you can autowire the module into your Spring-managed class and then register it with the ObjectMapper instance.  @Autowire Module jacksonHibernateModule;  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); mapper.registerModule(this.jacksonHibernateModule).

Comment: @EarthMind It may be too late, but for someone reading this now, Module is of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module and not java.lang.Module.

Comment: thanks @chrismarx, I'd give you 1337 upvotes for this answer if SO let me.

Answer (score 15):

This is similar to accepted solution by @rick.

If you don't want to touch existing message converters configuration you can just declare a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean like:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureObjectMapper() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
        .modulesToInstall(Hibernate4Module.class);
}
```

Do not forget to add the following dependency to your Gradle file (or Maven):

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate4:2.4.4'
```

Useful if you have a [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) application and you want to keep the ability to modify Jackson features from `application.properties` file.

Comment: How can we achieve  this (Configuring Jackson to avoid lazy loaded object) using `application.properties` file?

Comment: That's not what is being said here. @Luis Belloch's solution suggests that you create the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder so that you don't override spring boots default message converter and continue to use the application.properties values to control jackson properties.

Comment: sorry... I am new where would you implement this method?  With spring boot It uses Spring 5 which WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated

Comment: `Hibernate4Module` is legacy

Answer (score 11):

In the case of Spring Data Rest then, while the solution posted by @r1ckr works, all that is required is to add one of the following dependencies depending on your Hibernate version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Within Spring Data Rest there is a class:

`org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.Jackson2DatatypeHelper`

which will auto-detect and register the Module on application start-up.

There is however an issue:

[Issue Serializing Lazy @ManyToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395831/issue-serializing-lazy-manytoone)

Comment: How do you configure this with spring boot when you are not using Spring Data Rest?

Comment: Not enough. You also need `@Bean  hibernate5Module()`

Answer (score 7):

I've spent whole day trying to solve the same problem. You can do it without changing existing message converters configuration.

In my opinion the easiest way to solve this problem only with 2 steps with help of [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate):

> kotlin example (same as java):

1. Add In `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:$jacksonHibernate")
```

2. Create `@Bean`

```kotlin
   @Bean
   fun hibernate5Module(): Module = Hibernate5Module()
```

---

- Notice that `Module` is `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module`, not `java.util.Module`
- Also good practice is to add [`@JsonBackReference`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) & `@JsonManagedReference` to `@OneToMany` & `@ManyToOne` relationships. `@JsonBackReference` could be only 1 in class.

Answer (score 5):

The following solution is for Spring 4.3, (non-boot) & Hibernate 5.1 where we transitioned all fetchtypes to `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` from cases of `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` for performance reasons. Immediately we saw the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy` exception due to the lazy load issue.

First, we add the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then the following is added to our Java MVC configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    Hibernate5Module h5module = new Hibernate5Module();
    h5module.disable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
    h5module.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);

    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> mc : converters){
        if (mc instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter || mc instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) {
            ((AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) mc).getObjectMapper().registerModule(h5module);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Notes:

- You need to create and configure the Hibernate5Module to get behavior similar to Jackson without this module. The default makes incompatible assumptions.
- Our `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has a lot of other configuration in it and we wanted to avoid another configuration class, which is why we didn't use the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addDefaultHttpMessageConverters` function that has been referred to on other posts.
- `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#configureMessageConverters` disables all of Spring's internal configuration of message converters. We preferred to avoid the potential issues around this.
- Using `extendMessageConverters` enabled access to all the automatically-configured Jackson classes without losing the configuration of all other message converters.
- Using `getObjectMapper#registerModule` we were able to add the `Hibernate5Module` to the existing converters.
- The module was added to both the JSON and XML processors

This addition solved the issue with Hibernate and lazy loading but caused a **residual issue with the generated JSON format**.  As reported in [this github issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate/issues/97), the hibernate-jackson lazy load module currently ignores the @JsonUnwrapped annotation, leading to potential data errors. This happens regardless of the force-loading feature setting.  The problem has been there since 2016.

---

**Note**

It appears that by adding the following to classes that are lazy-loaded, the built-in ObjectMapper works without adding the hibernate5 module:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(  {"handler","hibernateLazyInitializer"} )
public class Anyclass {
```

Comment: The solution could be much more easier:  ```kotlin  @Bean
   fun hibernate5Module(): Module = Hibernate5Module()```

Answer (score 4):

If you use XML config and use `<annotation-driven />`, I found that you have to nest `<message-converters>` inside `<annotation-driven>` as recommended on the [Jackson Github account](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate).

Like so:

```
<annotation-driven>
  <message-converters>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
      <beans:property name="objectMapper">
        <beans:bean class="com.pastelstudios.json.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
      </beans:property>
    </beans:bean> 
  </message-converters>
</annotation-driven>
```

`

Comment: xml config is legacy

Answer (score 3):

For those who came here looking to find the solution for Apache CXF-based RESTful service, the configuration that fixes it is below:

```
<jaxrs:providers>
    <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider">
        <property name="mapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
    </bean>
</jaxrs:providers>

<bean id="objectMapper" class="path.to.your.HibernateAwareObjectMapper"/>
```

Where HibernateAwareObjectMapper is defined as:

```
public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
    }
}
```

The following dependency is required as of June 2016 (provided you're using Hibernate5):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following helper from Spring Data Rest project:

```
Jackson2DatatypeHelper.configureObjectMapper(objectMapper);
```

Comment: Not about the question

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple solution to this problem.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public Set<Pendency> getPendencies() {
    return Hibernate.isInitialized(this.pendencies) ? Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.pendencies) : new HashSet<>();
}
```

In my case I was giving the error because whenever I was returning a pendencies, as a good practice I converted it to a list that cannot be modified, but how it could or might not be in lazy depending on the method I used to get instance (with or without fetch), I do a test before it was initialized by Hibernate and add the annotation that prevents serializing an empty property and that solved my problem.

Comment: But when you need the actual data based on that object instance and Hibernate is supposed to really lazy load the data, it will not do it because it is already initialized?!

Answer (score 0):

We couldn’t work around the problem that we had to call `Hibernate.initialize(objX.getAttributeY())` for all Attributes.  So here we wrote a utils class to call the initialize methods on all attributes that have the Entity annotation.
Collections still must be handled separately.

```
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class HibernateInitialiseUtil<T> {

    private final List<Method> entityGetterMethods;

    public HibernateInitialiseUtil(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.entityGetterMethods = this.getGettersMethodsOfEntityAttributes(clazz);
    }

    public void initializeAllEntityAttributes(T obj) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        for (Method getter : this.entityGetterMethods) {
            Hibernate.initialize(getter.invoke(obj));
        }
    }

    private List<String> getNameOfEntityAttributes(final Class<T> targetClass) {
        Field[] attributes =  targetClass.getDeclaredFields();
        List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field attribute : attributes) {
            if (attribute.getType().isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)) {
                fields.add(attribute.getName());
            }
        }
        return fields;
    }

    private List<Method> getGettersMethodsOfEntityAttributes(final Class<T> targetClass) {
        List<Method> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String attributeName : getNameOfEntityAttributes(targetClass)) {
            try {
                PropertyDescriptor pd = new PropertyDescriptor(attributeName, targetClass);
                Method getter = pd.getReadMethod();
                resultList.add(getter);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IntrospectionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(resultList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

###### TLDR: Always serialize [DTO's](https://medium.com/javarevisited/not-so-obvious-tips-to-write-better-dtos-in-java-c6116895b180), avoid returning entities. Explicitly for OP question, answer is `@JsonIgnore`

---

The reason for the issue is that when retrieving lazily-loaded data, first step is populate the main object, and second to retrieve the data within its proxies. For this, an open Session in Hibernate is needed.

The problem arises when the second step happens after the transaction has closed, which leads to a `LazyInitializationException`.

I'm going to summarize some solutions here while adding mine:

```
1. Avoid entity serialization, **instead serialize a dto**
2. Add `@JsonIgnore` to your `LAZY` attributes
3. Change `FetchType` to `EAGER`
4. Set `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`
```

Only points 1 and 2 are recommended, the other 2 aren't meant to be used at serialization phase. As they have a HUGE performance cost there, they both make a hit to the database to retrieve extra data. **Option 4, actually creates a new transaction for every lazy object so please [AVOID!](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-loading-workaround#4-lazy-loading-with-automatic-transaction)**.

My grain of sand in this question is to highly recommend to explicitly use ONLY options 1 and 2, and also `FetchType.EAGER` only for business logic, not as a solution for this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I tried [@rick's useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21760361/606662), but ran into the problem that "well-known modules" such as [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) weren't automatically registered despite them being on the classpath. (This [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#jackson-modules) explains the auto-registration.)

Expanding on @rick's answer, here's a variation using Spring's [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html) to create the `ObjectMapper`. This auto-registers the "well-known modules" and sets certain features in addition to installing the `Hibernate4Module`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // get a configured Hibernate4Module
    // here as an example with a disabled USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION feature
    private Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module() {
        return new Hibernate4Module().disable(Hibernate4Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
    }

    // create the ObjectMapper with Spring's Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
    // and passing the hibernate4Module to modulesToInstall()
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                            .modulesToInstall(hibernate4Module());
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build());
  }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an update about this topic?
I'm having the issue currently. Ofcourse whenI add the `hibernate5Module` (because im using hibernate 5), jackson ignores the proxy of non initialized objects, but it seems that the " well-known modules" are not being registered despite I useyour approach. I do know this, because some parts of my application are broken, and when I remove the Module, they work again.

Comment: @DanielHenao Have you studied https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#customizing-the-jackson-objectmapper? I switched to Hibernate5, using the `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` class (instead of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`) as suggested by the [Jackson-Antpath-Filter](https://github.com/Antibrumm/jackson-antpathfilter): `@Override
 public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
  messageConverters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
  addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(messageConverters);
 }`

Comment: 1. `Hibernate4Module` is legacy . 2 `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` - not about the question

Comment: @DmitryKaltovich ad 1) it wasn't legacy at the time of writing; ad 2) ok, removed.

Answer (score -1):

Although this question is slightly different to this one : [Strange Jackson exception being thrown when serializing Hibernate object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362104/strange-jackson-exception-being-thrown-when-serializing-hibernate-object/), the underlying problem can be fixed in the same way with this code:

```
@Provider
public class MyJacksonJsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {
    public MyJacksonJsonProvider() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
        setMapper(mapper);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this, and worked:

// custom configuration for lazy loading

```
public static class HibernateLazyInitializerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JavassistLazyInitializer> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(JavassistLazyInitializer initializer, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
            SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeNull();
    }
}
```

and configure mapper:

```
    mapper = new JacksonMapper();
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule(
            "SimpleModule", new Version(1,0,0,null)
    );
    simpleModule.addSerializer(
            JavassistLazyInitializer.class,
            new HibernateLazyInitializerSerializer()
    );
    mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

Answer (score -4):

Another solution for spring boot:
configuration:
`spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`

Comment: This wouldn't help