# not able to resolve `HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting `HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session` error on `postman` window. Tried adding `@JsonIgnore`; but not successful. Not able to understand why is this happening. Below is code:

**config class**

```
package com.wpits.acf.core.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.mobile.device.LiteDeviceResolver;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.wpits.acf.core.security.AppSecurityConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConfigurationUtil;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages=
        {
        "com.wpits.acf.core.repository"
        })
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    })
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={
        "com.wpits.acf.core.exception",
        "com.wpits.acf.core.security",
        "com.wpits.acf.core.beans",
        "com.wpits.acf.core.security.filter",
        "com.wpits.acf.product.service",
        "com.wpits.acf.product.controller",
        "com.wpits.acf.*.service",
        "com.wpits.acf.*.resourceapi",
        "com.wpits.acf.*.beans"

        })
@Import(AppSecurityConfig.class)
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    private final static int maxUploadSizeInMb = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="dataSourceProp")
    public Properties dataSourceProperties() {
            Properties props=new Properties();
            props.setProperty("javax.persistence.provider", env.getRequiredProperty("javax.persistence.provider"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.handling_mode", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.handling_mode"));
            props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class"));
        return props;
    }


    @Bean(name="dataSource",destroyMethod="close")
    public DataSource configureDataSource(@Qualifier("dataSourceProp")Properties properties) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig=HikariConfigurationUtil.loadConfiguration(properties);
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }




    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory",destroyMethod="close")
    public EntityManagerFactory configureEntityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,@Qualifier("dataSourceProp")Properties jpaProperties){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean=new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.wpits.acf.core.model");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }



    @Bean("transactionManager")
     public JpaTransactionManager configureTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory bean) {
      JpaTransactionManager txm = new JpaTransactionManager(bean);
      return txm;
     }


     @Bean
     public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
            CommonsMultipartResolver cmr = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
            cmr.setMaxUploadSize(maxUploadSizeInMb * 2);
            cmr.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(maxUploadSizeInMb); //bytes
            return cmr;

        }




    @Bean 
    public LiteDeviceResolver deviceResolver(){
        return new LiteDeviceResolver(); 
     }






}
```

**Product Controller**

```
package com.wpits.acf.product.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.wpits.acf.core.model.Product;
import com.wpits.acf.product.service.ProductService;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;



@GetMapping(value = "productID/{productId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Product> getProductById(@PathVariable(value="productId",required=true)int productId) {
    System.out.println("reached here");
    Product product=null;
    product = productService.getProductById(productId);

    if(product!=null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(product,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}



}
```

**Product Service**

```
package com.wpits.acf.product.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.wpits.acf.core.model.Product;
import com.wpits.acf.core.repository.ProductRepository;

@Service
public class ProductService {
private final ProductRepository productRepository;

@Autowired
public ProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
    this.productRepository = productRepository;
}


public Product getProductById(int id) {
    return productRepository.findOne(id);
}
}
```

**Product Entity class**

```
package com.wpits.acf.core.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product", catalog = "anti_counter_feit")

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4378274718614532475L;
        private Integer id;
        @JsonIgnore
        private ProductCategory productCategory;
        private UserMaster userMaster;
        private String productName;
        private String productDealerId;
        private Date createdOn;
        @JsonIgnore
        private Set<Voucher> vouchers = new HashSet<Voucher>(0);

        public Product() {
        }

        public Product(ProductCategory productCategory, UserMaster userMaster, String productName, Date createdOn) {
            this.productCategory = productCategory;
            this.userMaster = userMaster;
            this.productName = productName;
            this.createdOn = createdOn;
        }

        public Product(ProductCategory productCategory, UserMaster userMaster, String productName, String productDealerId,
                Date createdOn, Set<Voucher> vouchers) {
            this.productCategory = productCategory;
            this.userMaster = userMaster;
            this.productName = productName;
            this.productDealerId = productDealerId;
            this.createdOn = createdOn;
            this.vouchers = vouchers;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_id", nullable = false)
        public ProductCategory getProductCategory() {
            return this.productCategory;
        }

        public void setProductCategory(ProductCategory productCategory) {
            this.productCategory = productCategory;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
        public UserMaster getUserMaster() {
            return this.userMaster;
        }

        public void setUserMaster(UserMaster userMaster) {
            this.userMaster = userMaster;
        }

        @Column(name = "product_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
        public String getProductName() {
            return this.productName;
        }

        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }

        @Column(name = "product_dealer_id", length = 45)
        public String getProductDealerId() {
            return this.productDealerId;
        }

        public void setProductDealerId(String productDealerId) {
            this.productDealerId = productDealerId;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false, length = 19)
        public Date getCreatedOn() {
            return this.createdOn;
        }

        public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
            this.createdOn = createdOn;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
        public Set<Voucher> getVouchers() {
            return this.vouchers;
        }

        public void setVouchers(Set<Voucher> vouchers) {
            this.vouchers = vouchers;
        }

    }
```

**ProductCategory Entity class**

```
package com.wpits.acf.core.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_category", catalog = "anti_counter_feit")

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class ProductCategory implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3766304364482482350L;
    private Integer id;
    private String productCategory;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);    
    public ProductCategory() {
    }

    public ProductCategory(String productCategory) {
        this.productCategory = productCategory;
    }

    public ProductCategory(String productCategory, Set<Product> products) {
        this.productCategory = productCategory;
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "product_category", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getProductCategory() {
        return this.productCategory;
    }

    public void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
        this.productCategory = productCategory;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "productCategory")
    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

}
```

**UserMaster entity class**

```
package com.wpits.acf.core.model;


import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_master", catalog = "anti_counter_feit", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"))

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class UserMaster implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2842909964796947777L;
    private Integer id;
    private Role role;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String mobile;
    private String email;
    private String fullName;
    private String companyName;
    private String companyAddress;
    private Date createdOn;
    private Date updatedOn;
    private boolean isActive;
@JsonIgnore
    private Set<VoucherAccessHistory> voucherAccessHistories = null;

@JsonIgnore
    private Set<Voucher> vouchers = null;

@JsonIgnore
    private Set<Product> products = null;

    public UserMaster() {
    }

    public UserMaster(Role role, String username, String password, String mobile, String email, String companyName,
            String companyAddress, Date createdOn, Date updatedOn,boolean isActive) {
        this.role = role;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.email = email;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.companyAddress = companyAddress;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
        this.isActive=isActive;
    }

    public UserMaster(Role role, String username, String password, String mobile, String email, String fullName,
            String companyName, String companyAddress, Date createdOn, Date updatedOn) {
        this.role = role;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.email = email;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.companyAddress = companyAddress;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "mobile", nullable = false, length = 15)
    public String getMobile() {
        return this.mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "full_name", length = 45)
    public String getFullName() {
        return this.fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @Column(name = "company_name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return this.companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    @Column(name = "company_address", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getCompanyAddress() {
        return this.companyAddress;
    }

    public void setCompanyAddress(String companyAddress) {
        this.companyAddress = companyAddress;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return this.createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_on", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getUpdatedOn() {
        return this.updatedOn;
    }

    public void setUpdatedOn(Date updatedOn) {
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }




    public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userMaster")
    public Set<VoucherAccessHistory> getVoucherAccessHistories() {
        return this.voucherAccessHistories;
    }

    public void setVoucherAccessHistories(Set<VoucherAccessHistory> voucherAccessHistories) {
        this.voucherAccessHistories = voucherAccessHistories;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userMaster")
    public Set<Voucher> getVouchers() {
        return this.vouchers;
    }

    public void setVouchers(Set<Voucher> vouchers) {
        this.vouchers = vouchers;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userMaster")
    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

}
```

When I start the server and hit controller through `postman`, I get below output:

[image]

how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957554/jsonmappingexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session)

Comment: ok let me check..

Comment: *Tried adding @JsonIgnore*: I don't see any such annotation on Product.productCategory (nor on Product.userMaster).

Comment: yes I removed it as it makes no difference to output

Comment: @rustyx the link provided by you, unfortunately did not solve my problem as the solved marked answer did not tell what exactly to do.

Comment: Add them back. It **wil** make a difference.

Comment: @JBNizet I deleted all the collection instance variables and added `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` in all entity classes. SAME OUTPUT. :(

Comment: So, I suggest to add a JsonIgnore annotation on Product.productCategory and Product.userMaster, and what you think that means is "delete all collection instance variables". Where is the logic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168496/discussion-between-jpg-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `@JsonIgnore` in getter of field

```
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);    
@JsonIgnore
public Set getProducts()
{

}
```

I assume this is your affected field, Otherwise add `jsonignore` on getter of appropriate field.