# Why serialized entity is wrapped with `content` when using Lazy `@ManyToOne`?

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, jackson, spring-data-rest

While using Jackson's [Hibernate4Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) to deal with the serialization issues when dealing with a lazily loaded proxy in a Spring Data Rest project.

In general it solves the issue of Jackson trying to serialise uninitialized proxies however one side effect is that the JSON output differs:

**Fetched directly: api/cases/5400**

```
{
   "id": 5400,
   "practiceReference": "DWPYI9"
}
```

**Fetched via a lazily loaded @ManyToOne: api/submissions/11901/parentCase**

```
{
   "content": {
      "id": 5400,
      "practiceReference": "DWPYI9"
   }
}
```

**Fetched via a non-lazily loaded @ManyToOne: api/submissions/11901/parentCase**

```
{
   "id": 5400,
   "practiceReference": "DWPYI9"
}
```

As can be seen in the above, the JSON representation differs when serializing a lazy `@ManyToOne` association: the entity is wrapped in the `content` node.

If the association is non-Lazy then the same representation is written regardless of the path.

**Is there a reason for this and can the additional "content" node somehow be prevented?**

---

**UPDATE FEB/2017:**

I have found the same (deleted) question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194554/two-different-resulting-jsons-when-serializing-lazy-objects-and-simple-objects

Which is referenced from [this github issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate/issues/77). Also, it is reported [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate/issues/97), so seems like a known issue: