# @ManyToOne Unidirectional Parameter value does not match expected type

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i've been trying to debug this problem, unfortunately i need another pair of eyes to see this. Its already confusing on my part. Can't seem to get around the problem. See below for source and db erd

[image: Database ERD]

The above shows the relationship. A User can have many Posts and Posts can only belong to 1 User. Below is my JPA code

Posts.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {

    ... Some other fields ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "uid")
    private User user;


    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    ... Some getters/setters  ...

    ... toString() ...

}
```

Users.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long uid;
    private String username;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String mail;

    ... getters and setters ...

    ... toString() ...
}
```

PostRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    List<Post> findByUser(Long uid);

}
```

PostServiceImpl.java

```
@Component
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    PostRepository repo;

    public List<Post> getPostByUser(Long uid){
        List<Post> posts = repo.findByUser(uid);
        logger.info("returning {}",posts);
        return posts;
    }

}
```

My problem is that when i try to request for all Posts under a User (userid=1), it gives me an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [com.web.santa.models.User (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:385) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.3.Final.jar:5.3.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.lambda$setParameter$3(QueryParameterSetter.java:111) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$ErrorHandling$1.execute(QueryParameterSetter.java:175) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:111) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.lambda$bind$0(ParameterBinder.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.invokeBinding(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:244) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:171) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:210) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:583) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:583) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.findByUser(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.web.santa.services.impls.PostServiceImpl.getPostByUser(PostServiceImpl.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.web.santa.controllers.UserCtrl.getPostByUserId(UserCtrl.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:799) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1012) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:904) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:889) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.web.santa.security.filters.JwtAuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthTokenFilter.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:112) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

So i don't understand what's wrong, maybe i've been debugging this for quite a while now so i need help and another set of eyes to see what's wrong with my code.

Things to Note

1.) I don't need a bidirectional relationship for user since, when I add/update post, i don't need to update User information. I only need the user information for displaying purposes to FrontEnd (UI). That is why i only need unidirectional relationship wherein for every post, i need to attached the User information.

2.) The above source code is used on REST-API endpoints only, meaning FrontEnd can be on a separate server

*** **UPDATE** ***

@Brother's Answer, i changed the repository interface as stated

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.user.uid = ?1")
List<Post> findByUser(Long uid);
```

However, the exception occured

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.web.santa.models.Post["user"]->com.web.santa.models.User$HibernateProxy$wLjffvP8["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
```

Comment: What type does your parameter have instead of `com.web.santa.models.User`?

Comment: @Thomas doesn't say though, or i might have misread it but i'll put the complete stack trace in the post. see my updates. Maybe the findByUser() method? it accepts User type as parameter..

Comment: @Thomas i also added my definition of Repository and Service Implementation

Comment: the DSL is wrong. You are saying to findByUser, but providing the Long for uId.

Comment: Modify the method to accept Users obj and to get Users object, create repository interface for Users and get users object by passing uid

Comment: The exception you get indicates you need to either tell jackson how to "serialize" (i.e. unproxy and then serialize) a Hibernate proxy or unproxy that yourself. There's probably a [Jackson databind plugin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) that provides support for Hibernate proxies.

Comment: Ohh, seems to be they're not supporting it due to something about not being used. But thanks thought pointed me to the right direction. For those trying to solve the serializing issue for lazy load, it is on a different question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395831/issue-serializing-lazy-manytoone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you could change the DSL to:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    List<Post> findByUser_uid(Long uid);

}
```

This way, you can receive the user id. Or:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.user.uid = ?1")
    List<Post> findByUser(Long uid);

}
```

Comment: I used the second way, by defining the `@Query` , however, there was an exception. See updates.

Comment: List<Post> findByUser(@Param("uid") Long uid);

Comment: @Rajesh, doesn't solve the exception error. its the same

Comment: Add this class level annotation to model classes
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})

Comment: @Rajesh, yep i added the said source, it fixed it. trying to understand why it was fixed.

Comment: @lemoncodes This happens because probably the database entity is been returned in a controller direct and hibernate adds this two properties dynamic to handle lazy load entities. One approach always creates the DTO for them, instead of returning the entity itself.