# Spring Data Rest POST response different from GET response

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-rest

On my Spring Data Rest project I have a `Competition` entity that references an `GeoLocation` entity:

```
public class Competition {
    @Id
    private String uname;

    [...]

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private GeoLocation geoLocation;
}

public class GeoLocation {
    @Id private Long id;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
}
```

Since every `Competition` must have a `GeoLocation` defined, the `Competition` entity handles the creation via `cascade`. When creating a new `Competition` entity via POST, I get the following response:

```
{
    "uname": "Some Competition",
    "geoLocation": {
        [content of geoLocation]
    },
    "_links": {
        [...]
    }
}
```

But when I call the newly created competition, the content of the `GeoLocation` will be wrapped in a `content` field.

```
{
    "uname": "Some Competition",
    "geoLocation": {
        "content": {
            [content of geoLocation]
        }        
    },
    "_links": {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I would expect that both requests would deliver the same response?

Comment: Possibly same issue as I asked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395831/issue-serializing-lazy-manytoone

Comment: @AlanHay that looks almost identical, thank you.

Comment: If so, making your relationship eager would probably solve.

Comment: You're right again @AlanHay. Changing to `Eager` solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JsonUnwrapped` solved this issue for me:

```
public class Competition {
    @Id
    private String uname;

    [...]

    @NotNull
    @JsonUnwrapped
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private GeoLocation geoLocation;
}
```