# Jackson: exclude every lazy collection on @Entity classes from serialization

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson, mapping, lazy-evaluation

In my Spring 4 project with Hibernate 5 and Java-based configuration I keep facing exception "could not initialize proxy - no Session " every time Jackson tries to serialize my entity with a lazy collection. It seems Jackson fails to check if collection is lazy and triggers loading which generates the exception.
How do I make Jackson avoid serialization of every lazy-loaded collection on every @Entity-class and thus avoid constant exceptions and fails with "no Session"? The simplest working solution.
I've read many approaches neighter of which really solves this problem for me.
Any help will be appreciated (not for Spring Boot!).
Some code snippet:

```
@Data
@Entity
@ToString(exclude="questions")
@Table(name = "theme")
public class Theme {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @OneToMany // LAZY by default
    @JoinColumn(name = "theme")
    private List<Question> questions;// = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

DAO

```
public interface ThemeDAO extends CrudRepository<Theme, Long> {
    List<Theme> findAll();
}
```

Exception goes here (in controller):

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(theme);
```

Comment: You can use `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Yes I know. But I sometimes need to retrieve this collection , e.g. I need it to work smoothly:  @Query("SELECT t FROM Theme t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.questions WHERE t.id=?1")
        Theme findOneWithQuestions(Long id); And that annotation will prevent me from doing this forever.

Comment: Have you looked at the [hibernate module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate)?

Comment: Yes, I found this add-on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-hibernate5. It seems to be the exact tool for it. But I found it has got few usages and deduced it is not very popular smehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708339/avoid-jackson-serialization-on-non-fetched-lazy-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) add-on really solved the problem.
I just added HibernateAwareObjectMapper as a separate class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module;
public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
            registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
    }
```

}

And then overrode the method configureMessageConverters in MVC configurer class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "learning_session.controller" })
public class WebContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(new HibernateAwareObjectMapper()));
            super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
// more beans 
}
```

Comment: And if I don't use Spring but plain JPA?