# How to prevent hibernate5 from lazy fetching when jackson serializes json object?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson, hibernate-5.x

I'm currently running a spring-boot application where an endpoint returns a Page of a particular object stored in the database. For our purpose lets call that object "x". Within "x" there is a list of objects that are set to be lazily fetched.

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
class x {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Integer id;

      @JsonIgnore
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "x", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      private List<y> lazilyFetchedList;

      @Override
      public Integer getId() {
           return id;
      }

      public void setId(Integer id) {
           this.id = id;
      }

      @JsonIgnore
      public List<y> getLazilyFetchedList() {
           return lazilyFetchedList;
      }

      public void setLazilyFetchedList(List<y> lazilyFetchedList) {
           this.lazilyFetchedList = lazilyFetchedList;
      }
}
```

I set `@JsonIgnore` above because I don't want `lazilyFetchedList` to be sent to the client upon a GET call.

My **problem** is, even though that **field is successfully ignored by jackson** as a client viewing the JSON response. But **additional querys are still made by hibernate** to fetch the `lazilyFetchedList` when serializing the Java object "x" (even though jackson is not using the result).

I have already tried answers from [Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708339/avoid-jackson-serialization-on-non-fetched-lazy-objects) but none of the answers seem to work.

Here is what my controller looks like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/x", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ApiResponse<?> findX(@PathVariable Integer id, PagingInfo info) {
        Page<x> page = repo.findX(id, toPageable(info));
        return toResponse(page, FIND_LIST_STATUS);
    }
```

Here's what my configuration of the object mapper looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApiWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    configureDefaultObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    customizeObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return objectMapper;
}

public static void configureDefaultObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);

    objectMapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());

    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, ZonedDateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, OffsetDateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
}

/**
 * Only register a json message converter
 */
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.clear();

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, ActuatorMediaTypes.APPLICATION_ACTUATOR_V1_JSON));
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());

    converters.add(converter);
}
}
```

Versions:

- Spring-Boot 1.5.3
- Jackson 2.8.6
- Hibernate 5.0.11.Final
- jackson-datatype-hibernate5 2.9.0

Comment: What happens if you remove the getter/setter?

Comment: Don't use entity class rather create pojo for json..

Comment: The thing is, I have alot of entities within my project. So creating a pojo for each one would not be a feasible solution, plus I wouldn't want to implement a solution which requires field changes in two different locations since there is a high chance the code would break if anyone were to update that entity. I would like a more general solution that's handled by the libraries themselves.

Answer (score 11):

Add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

(add the version if it is not managed by spring-boot-dependencies or spring-boot-starter-parent)
Add the following code to your spring configuration class:

```
@Bean
protected Module module() {
    return new Hibernate5Module();
}
```

With the following imports:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module;
```

Comment: I checked on this suggestion I am getting null like lazilyFetchedList : null