# Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

I tried to implement a REST service with Java, Hibernate, and Spring, which returns JSON.

I have map a many to many relation. I have a supplier that has a list of ingredients, and each ingredient has a list of suppliers.

I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier_ingredient (
  supplier_id BIGINT,
  ingredient_id BIGINT
)


ALTER TABLE supplier_ingredient ADD CONSTRAINT supplier_ingredient_pkey 
PRIMARY KEY(supplier_id, ingredient_id);

ALTER TABLE supplier_ingredient ADD CONSTRAINT 
fk_supplier_ingredient_ingredient_id FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) 
REFERENCES ingredient(id);

ALTER TABLE supplier_ingredient ADD CONSTRAINT 
fk_supplier_ingredient_supplier_id FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) REFERENCES 
supplier(id);
```

Then I have an **Ingredient** model:

```
.....
.....
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients")
@OrderBy("created DESC")
@BatchSize(size = 1000)
private List<Supplier> suppliers = new ArrayList<>();
....
....
```

Then I have a **Supplier** model:

```
....
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable( name = "supplier_ingredient ", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_supplier_ingredient_supplier_id"))
@OrderBy("created DESC")
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
@BatchSize(size = 1000)
private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
....
```

**Endpoint**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{supplierId:[0-9]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public SupplierObject get(@PathVariable Long supplierId) {

    Supplier supplier = supplierService.get(supplierId);

    SupplierObject supplierObject = new SupplierObject (supplier);

    return SupplierObject;

}
```

**Service**

```
....
public Supplier get(Long supplierId) {

    Supplier supplier = supplierDao.getById(supplierId); (it does entityManager.find(entityClass, id))

    if (supplier == null) throw new ResourceNotFound("supplier", supplierId);

    return supplier;
}
....
```

**SupplierObject**

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class SupplierObject extends IdAbstractObject {

    public String email;

    public String phoneNumber;

    public String address;

    public String responsible;

    public String companyName;

    public String vat;

    public List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    public SupplierObject () {

    }

    public SupplierObject (Supplier supplier) {

        id = supplier.getId();
        email = supplier.getEmail();
        responsible = supplier.getResponsible();
        companyName = supplier.getCompanyName();
        phoneNumber = supplier.getPhone_number();
        ingredients = supplier.getIngredients();
        vat = supplier.getVat();
        address = supplier.getAddress();


    }
}
```

And **IdAbstractObject**

```
public abstract class IdAbstractObject{

    public Long id;

}
```

My problem is, when I call the endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8080/supplier/1
```

I got an error:

> "Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of
> role: myPackage.ingredient.Ingredient.suppliers, could not initialize
> proxy - no Session; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily
> initialize a collection of role:
> myPackage.ingredient.Ingredient.suppliers, could not initialize proxy
>
> - no Session (through reference chain: myPackage.supplier.SupplierObject["ingredients"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->myPackage.ingredient.Ingredient["suppliers"])"

I followed this:

[Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708339/avoid-jackson-serialization-on-non-fetched-lazy-objects/21760361#21760361)

Now I haven't the error but in json returned, the ingredients field is null:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "email": "mail@gmail.com",
  "phoneNumber": null,
  "address": null,
  "responsible": null,
  "companyName": "Company name",
  "vat": "vat number",
  "ingredients": null
}
```

but in debug I can see ingredients....

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour of Hibernate and Jackson Marshaller
Basically you want to have the following: a JSON with all Supplier object details... included the Ingredients.

Please note that in this case you must be very carefull because you can have a cyclic reference when you try to create the JSON itself so you should use also [`JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) annotation

The first thing you must do is to load the Supplier and all its details (ingredients included).

How can you do it? By using several strategies... let's use the [`Hibernate.initialize`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize-java.lang.Object-). This **must be used before the closing of hibernate session** that is in the DAO (or repository) implementation (basically where you use the hibernate session).

So in this case (I assume to use Hibernate) in my repository class I should write something like this:

```
public Supplier findByKey(Long id)
{
    Supplier result = (Supplier) getSession().find(Supplier.class, id);
    Hibernate.initialize(result.getIngredients());
    return result;
}
```

Now you have the `Supplier` object with all its own details (`Ingredients` too)
Now in your service you can do what you did that is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{supplierId:[0-9]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public SupplierObject get(@PathVariable Long supplierId) 
{
    Supplier supplier = supplierService.get(supplierId);
    SupplierObject supplierObject = new SupplierObject (supplier);
    return SupplierObject;
}
```

In this way Jackson is able in writing the JSON `but` let's give a look to the `Ingredient` object.. it has the following property:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients")
@OrderBy("created DESC")
@BatchSize(size = 1000)
private List<Supplier> suppliers = new ArrayList<>();
```

What will happen when Jackson tries to create the JSON? It will access to the each element inside the `List<Ingredient>` and it will try to create a JSON for this one too.... also for the suppliers list and this is a cyclic reference... so you must avoid it and you can avoid it by using the JsonIgnore annotation. For example you may write your `Ingredient` entity class in this way:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value= {"suppliers"})
public class Ingredient implements Serializable
{
......
}
```

In this way you:

- load the supplier object with all the related ingredient
- avoid a cyclic reference when you try to create the JSON itself

In any case I would suggest to you to create specific DTO (or VO) object to use for marshalling and unmarshalling JSONs

I hope this is usefull

Angelo

Answer (score 15):

You have some solutions to resolve this issue:

1. You can use `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

But EAGER fetching is very bad from a performance perspective. Moreover, once you have an EAGER association, there is no way you can make it LAZY.

2. You can use `@ManyToMany @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`

More information: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/FetchMode.html

Edit: It can occur when you have the following line in yout `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view = false
```

Comment: changing: spring.jpa.open-in-view = true did the trick for me ...

Comment: ```spring.jpa.open-in-view = false``` My case.

Answer (score 3):

In my project I came across the same problem as yours. The problem is that by the time of reading the data "one to many" the session has already been closed. To get all the data, you need to explicitly initialize or use the transaction. I used an explicit initialization. 
You need to add a line in the DAO:

```
Hibernate.initialize(supplier.getIngredients());
```

After that, Hibernate will load all the data from the database. To avoid generating an exception when serializing to JSON, I add the `@JsonIgnore` annotation in the one-to-many model field.

Here is an example of my code:

1.Model

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "commandByEv", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Evaluation> evaluations;
```

2. DAO

```
public Command getCommand(long id) {
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Evaluation evaluation = session.get(Evaluation.class, id);
Hibernate.initialize(evaluation.getCommand());
return evaluation.getCommand();
}
```

Comment: My relation is manytomany, anyway, I don't understand your advice.
 first you say You need to add a line in the DAO: Hibernate.initialize(supplier.getIngredients());

then you write a DAO ... I'm confuse

Answer (score 3):

Just add `@JsonIgnore` after `@oneToMany` in your model class.

Comment: Does not work in my case.

Comment: it does not work because the direction of using @JsonIgnore is not specified, we should add it in the child class of the relationship, to break the cyclic barrier.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a jackson-datatype-hibernate.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate

And add this on your Application.java

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the hibernate session closed before the lazy initialization kicked in.

The solution is explained well at this answer below.
[Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708339/avoid-jackson-serialization-on-non-fetched-lazy-objects/21760361#21760361)

Comment: So, I tried like the example you linked, but now the ingredients in the returned json are null:

{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "123@gmail.com",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "address": null,
    "responsible": null,
    "companyName": "123123",
    "vat": "ddstere",
    "ingredients": null
}

I am using Hibernate 5 and for that, I am using Hibernate5Module instead of Hibernate4Module, like in your link

I am sure, I saw in debug, that the ingredients are present

Answer (score 0):

In my application.properties file open-in-view property of spring jpa was false. I had to comment to get rid of this.

```
 #spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

Hope this help somebody.

Comment: very bad pratice to enable that

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `spring.jpa.open-in-view = true` to application.properties

Answer (score 0):

See this issue comes, when we create a circular infinite loop.
It comes when we try to establish relationship.

`@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` or `@ManyToOne` from both directions i.e parent to child.

There could be several solutions to the problem.

I find the simplest one as to put

`@JsonIgnore` on the child child, which will break the loop to read the parent class again, and all data will come up efficiently !!!

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `spring.jpa.open-in-view = true` may solve the problem but is not advised for MVC application.

Usually, an MVC application works like this :

```
HTTP Request 
       |
        -> Controller 
                |   
                 -> Service 
                       |
                        -> Repository 
                               |
                    Service <-
                       |
          Controller <-
               |               
HTTP Response <-
```

Hibernate session is opened on the Service layer and closed once you return to the Controller.

Setting `spring.jpa.open-in-view = true` will open the session on the Controller layer and can therefore cause other issues you didn't have before.

This variable was originally created to handle sessions this way for application that use server templating (like thymeleaf or jsp for example).

To avoid the `failed to lazily initialize a collection` error without changing `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to true, try moving the code that is probably in your controller method to the service. If that is not an option, you can also open the session in your controller method. This will do the same than setting the variable to true but only for this method which is better.

You can find more info here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view