# Jackson serialization for non fetched lazy objects Hibernate 5 Spring 5

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

When Jackson try to serialize lazy object, i get an error:

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
```

I try to use this approach [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708339/avoid-jackson-serialization-on-non-fetched-lazy-objects), but i wasn't successfull. My config for jackson-modules

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module());
    messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    return messageConverter;
  }

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter());
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
  }
}
```

But i'm getting the same error. Could you explain me, what are I doing wrong?

My springboot version `1.5.15.RELEASE`, my jackson-datatype-hibernate5 version: `2.6.0`

Answer (score 1):

By default lazy loading feature is set to false.

To enable:

```
Hibernate5Module module = new Hibernate5Module();
module.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);
```

Comment: thanks, i knew about it, I asked how can i configure it, when i create mapper with special configuration i can use Hibernate feature, but when i return some Object from controller, Spring uses jackson controller without my settings. Can you help me, how can i configure jackson?